# How do we implement a cancel in plain Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I have a page and I display data in a table.
In each table I have a column with a `checkbox` which if is `checked` the user can modify the specific row via Javascript.
This is done as its `td` encapsulates either an `input` or a `select` and I make these editable for the user.
The user modifies the row and presses save and the changes are saved. So far ok.
My problem is how do I implement a `cancel`?
The user could choose many row i.e. check boxes and modify them but the user could also press cancel. On cancel the original values should be displayed (and the rows become non-editable again).
But how is a cancel operation implemented in Javascript? Do we store data in some global datastructures? Which would be this in Javascript?

Comment: do you want to *cancel* (rollback) or *stop*?

Comment: I would just keep a copy of all the form data, and re-populate.

Comment: @Sebas:`cancel` i.e. the user has made modifications to the `html` table but has not send anything to the server. I.e. return page as it was before editions

Comment: ah, well then it seems pretty straightforward to me. The first thing coming to my mind could be to add an invisible column exact replicate to the one you allow to modify, and use it to copy paste its value to the visible column on cancel. But really, it has to be clean, so I must say it depends how is your table originally being fed.

Comment: I know you're looking for a solution in plain javascript. But how about just reloading the page with its default values/settings?

Comment: well, you could also encapsulate a hidden field inside the `td` to store the old data and on cancel click you could repopulate with the value in the hidden field

Comment: I did that once. Generated the inputs with a `data-original` attribute, like `<input type='text' value='hello' data-original='hello' />`. At any time, if the user clicked on revert, I'd load the `data-original` into the `value`.

Comment: @showdev:There are no default values.The data are preloaded from DB

Comment: @acdcjunior:What is `data-original`?

Comment: @Sebas:1) There are 7 columns not one 2) The table is prepopulated from the database

Comment: @Cratylus The data preloaded from the DB would be the "default" values. Refreshing the page would reload those values. Just an idea.

Comment: Does this need to be done completely in Javascript? Normally, you're populating the form via the database so cancel would simply mean calling the database to repopulate the form after the clearing what the user wrote if anything. I guess you could either refresh the page so it reloads the data or you can do an ajax call and recall the data.

Comment: @showdev:I could do that but is it a good idea on each cancel to reload the data?I haven't worked much in front end and I don't know what are the standard things to do

Comment: In html5 you can add custom attributes to elements. Adding randomly named ones, like `<div mycustomattr='something'>...` would make your HTML **not valid**. Instead, you should use the `data-` prefix. See more here: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: @aug:Same comment I said to showdev

Comment: @Cratylus If you have a separate "cancel" for each row of the table, then it's probably better to use a different method (reload using ajax or from input attribute data). The refresh page idea would only work if there's a general "cancel" for the entire page/form.

Comment: @showdev:Good point.I had in mind a generic cancel

Comment: I didn't read all the comments, but another approach could be this: Don't replace the cell content with the form element. Keep the value (the text) in a `span` element and hide it when you show the form element. Then you don't have to do anything on cancel. Just show the `span` again and hide or remove the form element. Only update the `span` when the user wants to save the value.

Comment: Just an idea - when you click the reset button of a row, you could manually loop through all inputs in that row, wrap each in a `<form>`, then call `.reset()` on that form, then unwrap it. Of course, my example uses jQuery because it was a little less work, but it can easily be converted to not use it. I'm not sure of support and compatibility across browsers, but it seems to work in Chrome for me. Here's my example: http://jsfiddle.net/JeM8r/ . It was just a crazy idea of mine; I'm sure there's better ways, especially depending on your actual setup

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after the addition of informations you provided I suggest you setup the following mecanism:

```
function getDatas() {
var oXhr;

    //get datas from database:
    oXhr = new XMLHttpRequest();    
    oXhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (oXhr.readyState == 4 && (oXhr.status == 200)) {
        g_oData = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(oXhr.responseText, "text/xml");
        }
    }

    oXhr.open("POST", "yourphpscriptthatreturnsthexmldatas.php", true);
    oXhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
    oXhr.send();
}

function populateGrid() {
    //use g_oData to populate your grid, but at first totally clean the body
    var mygrid = document.getElementById("mygridid");
    //mygrid.innerHtml = "<table><tr><td>...</td></tr></table>";

    //use the xml library to parse g_oData and fill up the table:
    var xmlRows = g_oData.getElementsByTagName("TAG");
    var xmlRow;
    iLen = xmlRows.length;
    for (var i=0;i<iLen;i++) {
    xmlRow = xmlRows[i];
    //use xmlRow->textContent to build each cell of your table
    }
}

function revertChange() {
    //on cancel, revert the changes by populating the grid. 
    //it will use the global xml/json object loaded directly from database, to refill everything.
    populateGrid();
}
```

I did it myself many times to refresh some datas in a page. That's basically what you're doing except that you're not requesting anything to the database, you just refill the fields.

Comment: 1)What kind of object is `g_oData`? 2) What is `mygrid`? Something like `document.getElementById('table')`? Sorry I haven't worked much in the front end

Comment: What kind of object is g_oData?

Comment: if you choose xml, it will be an xmldomdocument. If you choose json, a json object. whatever you prefer. The most important thing is that it is global and remains in the page's private memory

Comment: Could you please write an example declaration?

Comment: @Cratylus See my example. Also, the xml parsing depends what you would return from php. But I imagine a mysql query that would allow you to return an xml text such as "<ROWS><ROW><COL></COL></ROW></ROWS>", or even the html table already designed? Your preference.

Comment: `mygrid.innerHtml = "<table><tr><td>...</td></tr></table>";` Is this an `html` table without data?

Comment: @Cratylus yes it was to give an example. You would have to go into the for loop and parse the dom nodes to build td per td I suppose

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [HTML5 `data-` attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) to implement a revert function. This way, each `<input>` would hold it's original value in case a `revert` button would be used.

Here's how it'd look:

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td><input type='text' value='change me' data-original='change me' /></td>
     <td><input type='text' value='change me2' data-original='change me2' /></td>
     <td><input type='button' value='revert' onclick='revert(this)'/></td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

And the code that reverts:

```
function revert(btn) {
    var parentTr = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
    var inputs = parentTr.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].type == 'text') {
            inputs[i].value = inputs[i].getAttribute('data-original');
        }
    }
}
```

The `data-original` attribute could be generated:

- By the server-side app who serves the page (**[see (1) demo fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/NkwV3/)**); or
- by a JavaScript function that is executed as soon as the DOM is ready [(**see (2) demo fiddle for this here**)](http://jsfiddle.net/NkwV3/1/).

As a side solution, you could store the **original values in a `map`** object. [**Here's the (3) demo for this**](http://jsfiddle.net/NkwV3/2/) (notice I added the `id` for each `input`, so it can be used as key to the `map`).

Keep in mind, though, neither solutions (2) or (3) require changing in server side code (the 3 assuming your inputs have ids). And (2) feels clearer.

**About the `defaultValue` attribute:**
 The `defaultValue` attribute can be a solution only if the value to be reverted never changes and if the fields involved are text `input`s.

Firstly, changing the "default value" is rather awkward and may break something else aling the page (one would expect the browsers make the `defaultValue` attribute read-only, but that does not seem to be the case). Secondly, you would be limited to `input`s of the text type.

Still, if none of that is a problem, the code above can be quickly adapted to use them instead of `data-` attributes.

Comment: Interesting.But I am not sure I use `HTML5`.I am writing the `body`. The headers are precreated and not sure if they are for `HTML5`

Comment: @Cratylus: that's okay, as long as you don't care about HTML validation.

Comment: @Alan:So browser will interpret it as `HTML5` independent of other headers?

Comment: @Cratylus HTML5 is specified by having `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your HTML page. Do you? If not, why not? :)

Comment: It works like this: You can add any extra attribute to HTML elements. That works, the browsers understand. The only downside is that this would make the HTML code invalid (but, again, it would work). The caveat is, if the attributes have the `data-` prefix and the validator is a HTML5 one, the HTML would still be valid (if they don't have that prefix, the HTML5 is invalid).

Comment: For the record, you could store those original values in a global `map`. But I personally believe it is clearer using `data-` attributes.

Comment: +1, was just writing out a similar solution. Using data attributes is much better than involving a global variable, it cleanly ties the data to the elements it is relevant to.

Comment: @Ian:The header part is not mine to modify :(

Comment: @Cratylus: No. However, you can still use javascript to interact with the data attributes, regardless of what you set the DOCTYPE to. If you run the code through an HTML validator, it will complain about the invalid markup. So if you don't care about markup validation, you can use this solution.

Comment: @Cratylus added the example using map. Check it out.

Comment: WTH would you need a data attribute for that? Have you never heard of the `defaultValue` property?

Comment: @Bergi:Isn't this only for `input` text?

Comment: @Bergi you're right that in the context of the example code (where the value is set inline) it doesn't make sense. But a case where data attributes help (and I'm not sure whether it's OP's case) is when field updates are made via AJAX. In such a case, using `defaultValue` you couldn't edit a field, save it, then re-edit while restoring the correct value. So what you do is set `data-original` each time the value is saved, and use that.

Comment: @Cratylus - but is it via AJAX or a full form submit (page navigates away)? If its a full form submit, @Bergi is right that setting your value="" attributes on the serverside, then using `defaultValue`, is the clean way to go.

Comment: @Ben:When the user presses save the values are send via ajax

Comment: While you can set defaultValue whenever doing an update to the field (it is not read-only as one would expect), I don't see how much better it is than a 'data-something' attribute. Feels rather confusing changing the defaultValue everytime (an Ajax call or other business event takes place).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty simple way:

Don't replace the cell content with the form element. Keep the value (the text) in a `span` element and hide it when you show the form element. Then you don't have to do anything on cancel. Just show the `span` again and hide or remove the form element. Only update the `span` when the user wants to save the value.

Here is an example. The showing and hiding is all done with CSS.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <span>value</span>
        <input type='text' value='' />
    </td>
    <td>
       <button class="save">Save</button>
       <button class="revert">Revert</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

JS:

```
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('table tr');

for(var i = 0, l = rows.length; i < l; i++) {
    rows[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        // all value display elements in the row
        var spans = this.querySelectorAll('span');
        // all form elements in the row
        var inputs = this.querySelectorAll('input');

        // handle click on save button
        if (event.target.className === 'save') {
            [].forEach.call(inputs, function(input, i) {
                spans[i].innerHTML = input.value;
            });
            this.className = '';
        }
        // handle click on revert button
        else if (event.target.className === 'revert') {
             // not much to do
             this.className = '';
        }
        else {
            // update form element values
            [].forEach.call(inputs, function(input, i) {
                input.value = spans[i].innerHTML;
            });
             this.className = 'edit';
        }
    });
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/R6cCF/1/)

Comment: +1.I think I understand what you describe.I don't understand the code

Comment: It's just an example so that I could present something that actually works ;)

Comment: Would it be too much to ask a small part in plain js as a headsup to understand what is going on?

Comment: No problem, give me some minutes. It will be very tide to the HTML structure though.

Comment: Turns out it's actually not too tide to it. But I used some modern functions for convenience (`querySelectorAll`, `forEach`). I updated the demo as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can just access the original `value` attribute of the input to get the `defaultValue`. Sample implementation:

```
$("table").on("dblclick", "td", function(e) {
    var val = $(this).html();
    $(this).empty().append($("<form/>").append(
        $("<input/>", {type:"text"}).attr("value", val),
        //                           ^^^^
        // set the *attribute*, as if it was present in the parsed HTML
        $("<button/>", {type:"reset"}).text("Reset"),
        $("<button/>", {type:"button", class:"cancel"}).text("Cancel"),
        $("<button/>", {type:"submit"}).text("Submit")
    ));
}).on("submit", "form", function(e) {
    var val = $(this).find("input:text").val();
    //                                   ^^^^^
    // which is equivalent to .prop("value")

    /* then do something with val, e.g. send it to server via ajax */
    $(this).parent().html(val);
    e.preventDefault();
}).on("click", "button.cancel", function(e) {
    var $form = $(this).parent(),
        $input = $form.find("input:text"),
        oldval = $input.attr("value");
    //                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // or .prop("defaultValue"), but not .val()!
    if (oldval == $input.val() || confirm("Do you really want to discard your changes?"))
        $(this).parent().html(oldval);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

([Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/nrkWW/1/))

A maybe more simple solution might be to use the dblclick-handler that creates the form as a closure and just store the original html in a local variable there.

Comment: Where do you use `defaultValue` in your code?Does this work for other types of elements? `select` or `checkbox`?

Comment: Getting the `value` attribute is equivalent to getting the `defaultValue` property. On checkboxes, there's `defaultChecked` (or just the `checked` attribute); On selects, the options have `defaultSelected` properties and their `selected` attributes